# В переменную записывается символ, а не строка

Tags: c++

```
good.open("goods.txt");
for(int i=0;i<ii;i++){
    good >> goods[i];
}
cout << goods[0];
```

ситуация следующая, в файле находится 3 слова. ii - переменная содержащая число 3 (good переменная типа fstream(если важно)), goods - string. Этот код должен поместить в переменную goods слова из файла и затем вывести их, но он помещает в переменную только 3 символа из первого слова, затем выводит только 1 символ. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, чтоб выводились слова, а не символы. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого `goods` должно быть массивом строк.

И - вы точно знаете это `ii`? Я бы делал так:

```
vector<string> goods;
for(string s; good >> s; goods.push_back(s));
```

Так вы получаете массив слов. естественно, выводить его как одну строку - не получится, выводите пословно:

```
for(const auto& s: goods) cout << s << " ";
```